# How to apply style using jsx-styled to an Image component

Tags: next.js, styled-jsx

Next.js introduced the Image component. I would like to use it and I am currently struggling to find the way to apply style to it using styled-jsx.

Here is my attempt:

```
export default function MyComponent({description}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Image src={concept.icon.url} className="icon" width={40} height={40}></Image>
            <div>{description}</div>
            <style jsx>{`               
                .icon:hover {
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
           `}</style>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The classname is properly transmitted to the underlying  dom element, but the style is not applied.
Is there some kind of incompatibility between next.js Image component and styled-jsx?

Comment: did u try putting the style INSIDE the Image component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `:global()` selector.

From `styled-jsx` documentation ([One-off global selectors](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#one-off-global-selectors)): "*This is very useful in order to, for example, generate a global class that you can pass to 3rd-party components.*"

**CODE:**

```
export default function MyComponent({description}) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Image src={concept.icon.url} className="icon" width={40} height={40}></Image>
            <div>{description}</div>
            <style jsx>{`               
                div :global(.icon:hover) {
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
           `}</style>
        </div>
    );
}
```